# What did the SG-1 effects people use to build and operate the MALPs?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, props

MALPs appear in numerous *SG-1* episodes. Their six wheel chassis appears similar to gas powered off-road vehicles which have been around for many decades.

From a production perspective, what was used to build the MALPs? They are depicted as electrically powered and remote controlled. Is that also true of the show props?

On occasion, MALPs have been depicted as having robotic manipulators. To what extent was that carried through in the props - was a show MALP actually equipped with a working robotic arm, or was it "movie magic"?

Comment: Great question. A real 'thinker'.

Answer (score 8):

### Mark 1 M.A.L.P.

The 'Mark 1' was a complete prop, made out of plywood, sheet plastic and thin metal sheets. The parts didn't articulate and any effects you see with the "robot arm" in the first two seasons are purely the result of 'special' effects with an operator holding the arm off-screen. As a matter of fact, the MALP didn't even drive itself, it had to be winched along by one operator and a second (off-screen) operator needed to wind the treads in the direction of travel.

The MALP itself was sold [at auction](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/7906702_malp) some years ago:

> **Technical Description:**
>
> Production made tank-like robotic vehicle, the base of the vehicle is
>   metal, it has a set of seven wheels on both sides of the base
>   surrounded by rubber tank tread arranged in a U shape around the
>   wheels, the body of the vehicle is a series of plastic boxes glued
>   together with various plastic cylinders and panels glued or bolted to
>   the boxes, on top of the right side box is a metal radar dish that
>   rotates and pivots on a plastic frame, **on the side of the left side
>   box is a robotic arm with a black plastic device on the end, on the
>   top center of the vehicle is a large robotic arm made out of sheet
>   plastic and plastic tubes, arm ends in a plastic robotic claw, arm and
>   claw do not move,** there are two non-functional lights attached to
>   the boxes facing forward, vehicle is painted silver with dark gray and
>   black panels and details, there are several written messages on decals
>   or stencils, vehicle shows wear from production use including some
>   missing panel pieces from the plastic body. Measures approx. 51in x
>   62.5in x 55.5in.

### Mark 2 M.A.L.P.

From Season 3 onwards, the Mk2 was made of rigid metal sheets and actually drove via remote-control. As you can see from the video below, the top piece (with the armature) actually removed to allow the special effects team to mount a camera. The robot arm still didn't actuate like a real arm, but I gather (from watching the show) that there was a working prop arm that did at least articulate in two dimensions, up and down.

---

The M.A.L.P. Mk2 was sold [at auction](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/8745708_malp) several years ago. Note the description of the functionality:

> **Technical Description:**
>
> This complicated piece of hardware was used throughout the series, and
>   is remote controlled. Production made large metal vehicle. Featuring a
>   metal chassis with 6 wheels and a metal enclosure. Includes a large
>   metal static claw on the front, an antenna dish on the side and
>   joystick controls on the back. Includes a box of accessories and a
>   remote control to run the unit. Unit is in working order and is
>   controlled by the remote and powered by two car batteries to move the
>   piece. Item measures 8 feet by 55in x 68in.

And the description of the ["Hero" arm prop](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/8745709_379-malp-arm-hero) that was used for closeups:

> Hero robotic arm placed upon the top of the M.A.L.P. in sequences
>   where the unit had to function. The arm that normally sat atop the
>   M.A.L.P. was a static prop.
>
> **Technical Description:**
>
> Production used large metal mechanical arm, made of metal and plastic
>   with electronic components. Item is untested. Measures 49in x 16in x
>   12in.

[image: Hero Arm Prop]

Comment: I had forgotten about the tracked version. I still looked to me like the 6-wheel version was based off a commercially manufactured ATV rather than  prop department build from the ground up.

Comment: @anthonyX - Like most things in TV-land, it's made out of apple boxes spray painted silver.